# Excel - comparing cells that return different format

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have 2 cells, `A1` and `B1`, both using Index + Match function that refers to other worksheets.

I then use `=if(A1=B1,TRUE,FALSE)` for verification but it failed to return the correct logic.

Formula Evaluation shows `=if(123="123",TRUE,FALSE)` and I found out that `B1` refers to a cell with text format.

Without changing other worksheets' cell format, how do I go about this?

Comment: are they always numbers stored as text? or can it be actual text?

Comment: `=--A1=--B1` perhaps (assumes A1 and B1 are either numbers or text-that-looks-like-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Comparing number to text even if showing the same value (123 as number and "123" as text) will result in False.

to convert the text into number and make the comparison proper you need to use "VALUE" function

try this:

> =IF(123=VALUE("123"),TRUE,FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

Can use `EXACT` function, it is case-sensitive but ignores formatting differences

```
 =if(EXACT(A1=B1),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).